# Joint distribution from conditional

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So the question is:

Let $\theta\sim U(0,1)$ and $X\mid\theta\sim\text{Binomial}(2,\theta)$.

Find the joint distribution of $(X,\theta) $

The way the lecturer started was the following:
$$ P(X=k, \theta <t)= \int_0^t P(X=x\mid\theta=s) f_{\theta}(s) \, ds=\int_0^t {2 \choose k}s^k (1-s)^{(2-k)} \, ds .$$

Then you can find the distribution depending on $k=0,1,2$.

But I don't understand why do we **integrate** the conditional probability times $f_{\theta}(s)$ which is just $1$ so we are left with the integral of binomial only. And even why with respect to $s$ (probability)... Really confused about this.

Would be great if somebody could explain it . Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your second line, is $X$ uniform on $(0,1)$ or $\theta$?

Comment: Ops, im sry. It was theta. Fixed.

Comment: do you know the Bayes rule?

Comment: Yes of course. I know you can easily re-arrange it for the joint but I don't understand why do we integrate the conditional distribution function.

Comment: Your MathJax coding style needs work.  See my edits. (In particular $X$~$U(0,1)$ was changed to $X\sim U(0,1)$, and \mid was used properly. And other things.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: How does your lecturer define the joint distribution of one continuous and one discrete random variable?

Comment: She did not define the joint distribution of one cts and one discrete random variable at all. But thanks for your explanation below.

Comment: Good question, and there are some tempting easy answers, but I am going to ponder this for a bit and try to post a _good_ answer.

Comment: Great! Awaiting impatiently :)

Comment: @MichaelHardy it seems implicit that my answer below is _not good_, which is fine but please let me know where it falls short.

Comment: @jesterII : Looking at it as a limiting process is what I meant as a "tempting easy answer", and it's not wrong, and in fact I know a highly respected mathematician who did it just that way under similar circumstances.  If I post an answer, then the answer to your question will be that I think my answer is a more proper way to think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be explained by first principles. Forget for a moment the particular distributions of $X$ and $\Theta$ and suppose that both $X$ and $\Theta$ are **discrete** random variables, where $\Theta$ takes non-negative values.

What we seek is the probability $P(\{X=k,\Theta \le t\})= P(\{X=k,\Theta=0\} \cup \{X=k,\Theta=1\}\cup \dots \cup\{X=k,\Theta=t\}) = \sum_{s=0}^t P(X=k,\Theta=s)$

where the first equality is simply an expansion of the event of interest, and second equality follows from the fact that each of the events is disjoint.

Using the multiplication rule, this sum can be re-expressed as $\sum_{s=0}^{t} P(\Theta=s)P(X=k\mid\Theta=s)$.

Now, the problem you have posed has $\Theta$ as a continuous random variable, so (for intuitive, non-rigorous purposes) the discrete sum becomes an integral, and the probability $P(\Theta=s)$ becomes the probability of a small interval  $dsf_\Theta(s)$. This is the limiting process from which we can intuitively arrive at the result you are asking about:

$$\sum_{s=0}^t P(\Theta=s)P(X=k\mid\Theta=s) \rightarrow \int_0^t ds \, f_\Theta(s) P(X=t \mid \Theta=s)$$

**Non-Limiting Argument**

The result can also be derived from a direct application of the law of total probability (perhaps another "easy answer"), without limiting arguments

$P\{X=k,\Theta \le t\} \\ 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dsf_\Theta(s)P\{X=k,\Theta \le t \mid \Theta =s\} \\
= \int_{0}^{1}dsf_\Theta(s)P\{X=k,\Theta \le t \mid \Theta =s\} \\
= \int_{0}^{t}dsf_\Theta(s)P\{X=k,\Theta \le t \mid \Theta =s\} + \int_{t}^{1}dsf_\Theta(s)P\{X=k,\Theta \le t \mid \Theta =s\}
$

Now, the second integral in the summation is zero, since for all $s >t$ we have in the conditional universe $P(X=k,\Theta \le t \mid \Theta =s ) = 0$.

As for the first integral in the summation, it is easy to derive that, for all $s \in [0,t]$ we have $P(X=k,\Theta \le t \mid \Theta =s ) = P(X=k \mid \Theta =s )$. Making the appropriate substitution, we arrive at the result

$P(X=k,\Theta \le t) = \int_{0}^{t}dsf_\Theta(s)P\{X=k \mid \Theta =s\}$

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanation.